Is there a way to filter aws resources by part of its name using cloud custodian?
In my project, the AMI names are in the following way
SERVICE_NAME-AMI_VERSION-PIPELINE_ID

I am using cloud custodian to implement some policies to delete old AMIs. I need to group the AMIs by this part of its name
SERVICE_NAME-AMI_VERSION

then delete all the amis of each group keeping the latest one. Is there any built-in functionalities to achieve this?
I referred the documentation, but could not find any clues
